# Can't login to new Sandbox accounts

Tags: paypal-sandbox

I've just created a new Paypal developer account and associated a new sandbox buyer account to it. A facilitator account was automatically created.

However, I cannot login to the sandbox using the sandbox buyer's credentials. I've tried changing the password and clearing my cookies and cache but still not luck.

The credentials for the facilitator account also do not work in the sandbox.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've used the "old" version of sandbox you'll need to clear your cache and cookies before being able to log in.

If you do not, you'll be receiving the error message below.

"This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address."

If you continue receiving a password error, trying resetting the password to the accounts by following the steps below:

```
Log into https://developer.paypal.com
Click Applications
Click Sandbox accounts
Expand the account in question
Click "Profile"
Click "Change Password"
```